# Scroll view working in emulator but not working in android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, scrollview

I have an scroll view in my app that works well in my emulator but not working in android device..... my app developed with `minsdkversion:8`...I deployed my app in **android 2.2**

My layout is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:scrollbars="vertical" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#D2691E"> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#D2691E"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Branch"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="30px"
/>
<Spinner android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/group_prompt"

/>   
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Year"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="30px" />
<Spinner android:id="@+id/year"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"


 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/year_prompt"

/>     

<Button android:id="@+id/ok1_button" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Ok1" android:ems="5">          
</Button>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Plz give a solution..Thanks

Comment: whats the problem on device ? view inside scrollview is frozen?

Comment: @Rahul garg ya.....i am not able to scroll in the device but i can able to scroll in emulator

Comment: on emulator how you are scrolling by scroll button of mouse or draging cursor

Comment: @kumar : Check my answer have updated after Testing.

Comment: ok have you tested my answer code

Answer (score 0):

In your 2 Snippers Replace your Code with

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#D2691E"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D2691E"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Branch"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:prompt="@string/stringone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Year"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:prompt="@string/stringtwo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok1_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="5"
            android:text="Ok1" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Copy and paste in your file. will work in both 2.1 and 2.2 .

Comment: @kumar : Have kept whole File, just copy and paste in your file.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


     <ScrollView  
     android:scrollbars="vertical" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:background="#D2691E"> 
    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D2691E"
    >
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Branch"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30px"
    />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/group_prompt"

    />   
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Year"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30px" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/year_prompt"

    />     

    <Button android:id="@+id/ok1_button" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Ok1" android:ems="5">          
    </Button>
     </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey now also i have given  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" attribute for each layout but it is working....what might be the reson for scrollview not work in my above code

Comment: okay then this may be because scrollview is not allowed in your device as parent layout this might be a reason which device you are using